# Sum ints on stdin

Tags: common-lisp

I have been meaning to learn LISP and for a small task I wanted to find out the sum of all integers on STDIN. So for

```bsh
> clisp a.lisp
1
2
3^D
6
```

My code is as follows. I have a small helper function, my core function and the invocation of it.

```lisp
(defun read-int()
  (parse-integer (read-line)))

(defun sum-stdin()
    (handler-case
      ; recurse
      (+ (read-int) (sum-stdin))
      ; base case: if eof
      (error(c)
        (values 0))))

(write (sum-stdin))
```

Is this according to "the lisp way"?

One thing I see is that it feels weird to basically have the base case of my recursive function what would otherwise be the catch block in a non-functional language. I don't think there is a rule against it, but it just seems very unusual and hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dealing with *end of file* in I/O operations**:

There are two basic ways to deal with EOF in functions like `read-line`:

*1) Return a value*

```
           ; stream     ; signal eof error     ; return value if EOF
(read-line stream       nil                    nil)
```

*2) Signal an error*

```
           ; stream     ; signal eof error
(read-line stream       t)
```

Typical way:

- use a loop, like SDS said
- don't signal an error, but deal with an explicit EOF value

Less typical:

- use a loop, like SDS said
- signal an error and handle it -> might need slightly more tricky error handling code

Possible:

- use a loop, like SDS said
- hide the error handling code behind a macro...

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not lispy at all.

Lispers use recursion only when necessary, not as a generic substitute for iteration. Moreover, even in scheme they use *tail* recursion instead of iteration, and your code is not tail recursive.

A typical lisp solution would be

```lisp
(defun sum-stream(&optional (s *standard-input*))
  (loop for line = (read-line s nil nil) while line
      sum (parse-integer line)))
(print (sum-stream))
```

Comment: I would really liked to have given this the answer checkmark -- because it *shows* the better solution. But the other answer starts to explain the proper way, so it seems more "complete"